# Not able to create heroku-redis for my heroku application

Tags: django, heroku, redis

I have been trying to add a heroku-redis add on to my django application deployed on heroku,usually free add-ons like heroku PostgreSQL and heroku-redis should not need me to verify my account with billing but for some reason I can't create a heroku-reddis add-on but can normally create Heroku Postgres add-on.

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: Screenshot of notification saying "Item could not be created, Please verify your account..."]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> usually free add-ons like heroku PostgreSQL and heroku-redis should not need me to verify my account

That's not quite right. Among other reasons, [account verification is required to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#when-is-verification-required) (emphasis added):

> Add any add-on to the app, even if the add-on is free. The only exceptions to this are the free plans for the Heroku Postgres and Heroku Connect add-ons, which can be used without verification.

So, yes: You can use the free tier of Heroku Postgres without account verification. But in general, to add an addon, even a free one, your account must be verified. That includes Heroku's Redis service.

As long as you stick to free services, you won't be billed (though you [may see a temporary hold while verification takes place](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification#credit-card-charge-verification-hold)).